# c++ Read two words from text file into single char array

Tags: c++, arrays, io

I am trying to read "firstname lastname" from a .txt file. This is the code I have (it doesnt work, it only copies the first word) and it ultimately messes up my program on the whole. How can I fix this. please, only helpful replies

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Structs
struct card {
  char suit[8];
  char rank[6];
  int cvalue;
  char location;
};

struct player {
  char name[100];
  int total;
  card hand[];
};

int main() {
  player people[4];
  /open player names file
  ifstream fin2;
  fin2.open("Players.txt");
  // check if good
  if (!fin2.good()) {
    cout << "Error with player file!" << endl;
    return 0;
  } else {
    int j = 0;
    fin2 >> people[j].name;  //prime file
    while (fin2.good()) {
      j++;
      fin2 >> people[j].name; //copy names into people.name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where is `people` declared?

Comment: what does the Players.txt file look like?

Comment: We are the `people`.

Comment: people is declared right under main. dont ask questions you can answer yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the input stream operator (>>) on a text file will read until the first white space is encountered (i.e. space, tab, newline). Your code `fin2 >> people[j].name` will only read the first word from the file so you need to do it again to get the second word. However, if you just do the same thing twice you'll end up with the second word as it will overwrite the first. You could do something like:

```
fin2 >> people[j].name;       // read first name
n = strlen(people[j].name);   // get length of first name
people[j].name[n] = ' ';      // insert the space
fin2 >> &people[j].name[n+1]; // read last name
```

Alternatively, if there is only one name on each line, you can use the getline() function.

```
getline(fin2, people[j].name);
```